# Book(s) where an AI transforms humans into (bio)mechanical soldiers

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, artificial-intelligence

I saw a review of aliens from a book series on YouTube about a week ago, and was wanting to check it out but don't remember the name.

The books are about humans who, being humans, attacked an alien alliance and got their teeth kicked in so much they were pushed back to Earth, and so they enacted an emergency measure, activating an experimental AI. After activating the AI, it decided humans as-is were too weak, so it turned them into vaguely bug-like bio-machines designed to wage war, which would conquer worlds just to turn them into 'womb worlds', whose entire purpose is to crank out more troops.
Does anyone know what it's called?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like **Humanity Lost**, a comic series in development by Callum Stephen Diggle.

From [Diggle's Patreon](https://www.patreon.com/CallumStephenDiggle):

> [...] Humanity Lost, a science fiction comic book series chronicling the adventures of the last human through an indifferent and perilous galaxy. A galaxy filled to the brim with non-humanoid aliens and bio-mechanical horror.

It's exactly as you describe - a defeated humanity gives control to an AI to win a war, at the cost of their humanity, and expand to consume, conquer, and convert worlds to suit its needs.

[Here's a video](https://youtu.be/MxVjFYi-9JU) about it - go to about 4:25 for the mention of "womb-worlds".

Comment: It's funny; I coincidentally watched the YT video I posted about ten minutes after reading the question (it had been queued up in my "watch later" list for a while). When womb-worlds were mentioned it really jumped out at me.